# How to add your Database object ID related to a User to the session storage using callbacks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have a social media project where authentication is covered by next-auth, there are 3 providers right now, GithubOauth, GoogleOauth and Credential(local username password), I have a signIn callback that checks if email in that provider exists, if email exists just return, or else Register the User

`async signIn({ user, account }) {
console.log("User:", user);
console.log("Account:", account)

```
        const accountType = account.provider;
        const name = user.name;
        const email = user.email;

        try {

            await connectMongoDB();
            const userExists = await User.findOne({ email })

            if (!userExists) {
                const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4452/api/user/register', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        name,
                        email,
                        accountType
                    })
                })

                if (res.ok) {
                    console.log(res);
                    return user;
                }
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error: ", error)
            return null;
        }
        return user;

    }`
```

I have tried to access the the User argument in the session callback but it always comes back as undefined and I use UseSession hook to fetch data from persisted session, but I want to add Id field to the session and other schema changes.

How can I access the Session object in signIn callback or the User Object in session callback
All of my Code is largely dependant on the ID of a User like setting up sockets for live chat and notifications,

Is there anyway to persist just the mongoDB ID into the sessionStoarage System?

I wanted to persist more information in the session storage, however they just give out name, email and maybe pfp, I want to connect it to database using ID. and its not letting me access the User Object in session callback and no session storage in signin callback